# Flatten Unflatten the Data Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot, pivot-table

How to change the columns containing Small_X, Large_X (Where X is numbers 1,2,3,... etc) need to be un-flattened with all other values propagated to the new records and a new column called "New_Column" will be added that denotes the X value.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Time':  ['12/1/19 0:00', '12/1/19 0:05'],
    'Small_1': [1, 0],
    'Large_1': [0, 0],
    'Con_1': [0, 0],
    'Small_2': [0, 0],
    'Large_2': [0, 0],
    'Con_2': [0, 0],
    'Small_10': [1, 0],
    'large_10': [0, 0],
    'Con_10': [0, 0],
    'Some_other_value': [78, 96],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Above input data should result in the following Format using Pandas.

[image]

Comment: Please include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), instead of images.

Comment: (1) As mentioned above, a code that creates few rows of the DataFrame shown in the top screenshot would help. (2) Also, it is unclear how to handle the `1` from say `Small_10`. Would that replace the `1` from `Small_1` etc. Assuming each timestamp has different values in each set of columns for `Small`, `Large`, and  `Con`.

Comment: The above screenshot is already created CSV in which all the attributes are there numbered as small_1, large_1, con_1 .... small_10 and so on. Timestamp should be grouped later so that for each small_X, large_X it converted to small and Large resp. @NileshIngle

Comment: @Mr.Robot: (1) Sorry for not being clear, I meant a code that we can copy/paste to create the `DataFrame` in question would be helpful. So that we do not have to manully type the numbers from the `Screenshot 1` to create the dataframe on our side. (2) Would the timestamp say `12-01-2019 00:00` be repeated `10 times` when the columns `Small_1` to `Small_10` are converted to the format shown in `Screenshot 2`? Assuming then, that the `Screenshot 2` posted above is a after the data is `grouped`.

Comment: (1) Okay I'm adding the sampe DataFrame in the Question so that it would be more convenient. (2) Yes it would repeat for every X but not for small large or con. @NileshIngle

Comment: @NileshIngle I updated the question. I hope this would be more convenient

Comment: @Mr.Robot: Thanks. I've posted the answer that outputs aggregate value of `np.max`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative code:

Code below uses `.stack()`, `.unstack()` and `.pivot_table()`. It selectively only picks column names that have the strings `small`, `large`,`con` specified in list `key` to be split.

**Note**:

1. *The output is aggregated by `aggfunc=np.max` in the `.pivot_table()`. This could be changed to any other type of aggregation method as needed such as `np.min`, `np.sum`, or a custom function*.
2. *The original column names were changed to lower case, except `Time`*

Code:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame (copy pasted from question above)
data = {'Time':  ['12/1/19 0:00', '12/1/19 0:05'],
    'Small_1': [1, 0],
    'Large_1': [0, 0],
    'Con_1': [0, 0],
    'Small_2': [0, 0],
    'Large_2': [0, 0],
    'Con_2': [0, 0],
    'Small_10': [1, 0],
    'large_10': [0, 0],
    'Con_10': [0, 0],
    'Some_other_value': [78, 96],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Set Time as index
df = df.set_index('Time')

# Rename columns
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower() # change case to lower

# Stack
df = df.stack().reset_index() # convert columns to rows

# Split based on condition
key = ['small', 'large','con'] # Column names to be split
df['col1'] = df['level_1'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[0] if x.split('_')[0] in key else x)
df['New_Column'] = df['level_1'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[1] if x.split('_')[0] in key else np.NaN)

# Drop/rename columns
df = df.drop(['level_1'], axis=1)
df.columns.name=''

# Pivot using aggregate function: np.max
df = df.pivot_table(index=['Time', 'New_Column'], columns='col1', values=0, aggfunc=np.max)

# Rearrange
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns.name=''
df = df[['Time','small', 'large', 'con', 'New_Column']]
```

Output

```
print(df)

           Time  small  large  con New_Column
0  12/1/19 0:00      1      0    0          1
1  12/1/19 0:00      1      0    0         10
2  12/1/19 0:00      0      0    0          2
3  12/1/19 0:05      0      0    0          1
4  12/1/19 0:05      0      0    0         10
5  12/1/19 0:05      0      0    0          2
```

Comment: That's pretty much according to my requirement. Need to do few changes. Else it was fine. thanks a lot @Nilesh

Answer (score 1):

I am proposing first to `filter` columns of interest, then to `melt` the columns, then `split` columns name on "_" then `pivot` the dataframe:

```
# Filter columns
df = df.filter(regex=r"^([Cc]on|[Ll]arge|[Ss]mall|Time).*") 

# Melt dataframe
new = df.melt(id_vars="Time")

# Split column name
new[["variable", "New_Column"]] = new.variable.str.split("_", expand=True)

# Set variable as title
new["variable"] = new.variable.str.title()

# Pivot dataframe
new = pd.pivot_table(new, index=["Time", "New_Column"], values="value", columns="variable")

print(new.reset_index())
```

Comment: @Mr.Robot, I updated my answer to select columns of interest